# How to use Ninject to pass Initialized Instance into Web API Controller's Constructor

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject, self-hosting

I am trying to use Ninject to inject dependency into a Self-host Web API Controller. I am success to inject the dependency as follows:

```
    public static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<ITestAlert>().To<TestAlert>();
            return kernel;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

and

```
    var server = WebApp.Start(baseAddress, (appBuilder) =>
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(NinjectConfig.CreateKernel());

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    });
```

However, what I want to do is to pass an initialized instance from outside into the Controller's constructor. For instance, I have initialized an instance

```
public interface ITestAlert
{
    string Fullname { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class TestAlert : ITestAlert
{
    private string _fullname;

    public string Fullname
    {
        get
        {
            return _fullname;
        }
        set
        {
            _fullname = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The instance is initialized as

```
public ITestAlert _testAlert;

_testAlert = new TestAlert
{
    FullName = "Dummy"
};
```

What I expect is to get "Dummy" output string from the Get action method of the Controller,

```
 private ITestAlert _testAlert = null;

 public ValuesController(ITestAlert testAlert)
 {
     _testAlert = testAlert;
 }

 public string Get()
 {
     return _testAlert.Fullname;
 }
```

However, I can only get a "null" return! Would you please advise how to pass the initialized instance into the Controller's constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a dedicated binding should do the trick :

`kernel.Bind<ITestAlert>()
   .ToConstant(new TestAlert{FullName = Dummy"}).WhenInjectedInto<ValuesController>();`

Comment: @user1133555 nice! Dont' forget to accept the answer